# Check for duplicate email address but exclude current user

Tags: php, sql, validation, pdo, duplicates

I've created a user login system and have a page where users can update their details. The email address and username need to be unique so I added validation to the update form. However, when the form is submitted it errors saying the email address is already in use. 
Can I exclude the current email (stored in the session) from the duplicate check somehow?

This is my code, but not all as it's a bit long, I also need to do the same validation check for the username:

```
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT email, username, firstname, middlename, lastname FROM members WHERE memberID = :memberID');
        $stmt->execute(array(':memberID' => $_SESSION['memberID']));
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }

    //process form
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        // email validation
        if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        } else {
            $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM members WHERE email = :email');
            $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
            $emailcheck = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if(!empty($emailcheck['email'])){
                $error[] = 'Email provided is already in use.';
            }
        }

        // insert to DB
        if(!isset($error)){ 

            try {
            $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE members SET username=:username, firstname=:firstname, middlename=:middlename, lastname=:lastname, email=:email, updated=NOW() WHERE memberID = :memberID');
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':username' => $_POST['username'],
                    ':firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
                    ':middlename' => $_POST['middlename'],
                    ':lastname' => $_POST['lastname'],
                    ':email' => $_POST['email'],
                    ':memberID' => $_SESSION['memberID']
                ));

            //redirect to page with updated message
            header('Location: personal-details.php?action=updated');
            exit;

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                $error[] = $e->getMessage();
            }

        } else {
            $error[] = 'Update error';
        }

    }
```

Then in each text box I used:

```
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo($row['username']) ?>" tabindex="1">
```

Comment: Are you talking about **user login** or **user registration** page? In User login, the username MUST exist. In User Registration, the username MUST NOT exist (same for E-mail).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `memberID` like you do in the other queries as well, but excluding it:

```
SELECT email FROM members WHERE email = :email AND memberID != :memberID
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So simple, and yet I just couldn't figure it out